# found \N in my data does not count as missing values in r

Tags: r, rstudio

So scrolling through my columns I find \N embedded. I need to count them, but I get an error.  Would it be considered a missing value, it's new to me.

```
# Check whether attribute HeadOfState in country has any missing values, and if so, how many.
country$headOfState[country$headOfState==""] <- NA
country$headOfState[country$headOfState==\N] <- NA
sum(is.na(country$headOfState))

# Check whether attribute IndepYear in country has any missing values, and if so, how many.
country$IndepYear[country$indepYear==""] <- NA
country$indepYear[country$indepYear=='\N'] <- NA
sum(is.na(country$indepYear))
```

Error: unexpected input in "country$headOfState[country$headOfState==\"

> country$headOfState[country$headOfState==\N] <- NA
>   Error: unexpected input in "country$headOfState[country$headOfState==\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its shorws an error, bacause '\' is a part of base regex expressions in R.
As states [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

**The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?**

So the comparisson like this

```
country$indepYear=='\N'
```

or this ( Its not a valid comparisson at all)

```
country$headOfState==\N
```

will throw an error. You need to "escape" the "\" symbol. 
Try something like this instead if you want to replace "\N" with NA:

```
country$indepYear[country$indepYear=='\\N'] <- NA
```

If you need just to count them, you can use this approach:

```
sum(country$indepYear=='\\N')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much that definitely solved the problem.

Comment: @ChrisKehl you are welcome